# How can I get a flex-bit unstuck if the shank is stripped?

Tags: drill

We have a flex-bit stuck in wood - tried to drill it through the ceiling and the shank (bottom part of the bit) stripped so now it can't be "locked" to the chuck of the drill.
Is there any way to adapt a stripped shank/attach another drill bit/shank to it?

Follow up question - if you couldn't get it out - who would be the professional you'd call?

Comment: What kinda bit (round or hex, steel shaft or braided flex) and drill (keyless chuck)?

Comment: It was hex, but it's all stripped. The drill is keyless chuck.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a steel shank drill bit, grind off where it's striped, ~2". Otherwise just skip to grinding three flats, 120 degrees apart to give the chuck something to grab. Back the bit out and start over with a nice, fresh battery. Corded drills with keyed chucks are way down in price. Using one of them could most likely get you out of this situation and would probably have avoided this in the first place.

---

You were using something like [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/11-28cm-FLEXIBLE-FLEX-QUICK-CHANGE-DRIVER-ANGLE-EXTENSION-SHAFT-1-4-x11-POWER-TOOLS/1952013137.html), hex-headed flexible extension in a cordless, keyless-chuck drill.

[image]

When you should of been using [this](http://www.lashen.com/vendors/greenlee/hole_making.asp), 4' flexible drill bit, keyed in a corded drill's chuck with a handle.

[image]

Comment: If space limitations were the need for the flexible bit, I'd of used my right angle drill which I find invaluable. If you really like hex-head style, consider buying a 1/4" impact driver. I've probably voided the warranty by putting spade drill bits into it, but it sure works nice. @Michal

Comment: We are using the bit that looks like the one in the second picture. The problem is is that the part that should connect to the drill is stripped.And the angle is above our heads - it's in the ceiling...

Comment: I just looked at mine; it isn't hex, but it does have 3 factory 'flats' on it. You need to grind or file these flats back on it, or even a keyed chuck might still spin on it. @Michal

Comment: Just found myself in OP's situation and thought of the same solution (file off 3 flats to let the chuck grip the shank tighter). Searched here for validation. Confirm that it works!

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by seeing if I could get a set of locking pliers to clamp onto the shaft and try to turn it by hand.

Comment: Using a strap wrench to tighten the drill's collet around the bit might also work (assuming the collet is keyless).

Comment: Would these work on a flex-bit where the tip of it is a few feet away?