# How to arrest Cat6 cables from falling inside the wall?

Tags: walls, data-wiring, ethernet

I successfully drilled through floors (see [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/219591/stuck-drilling-wood-frame-between-floors)), pulled Cat6 cables and terminated them with keystones. I tested everything  and now am ready to finish the installation by installing wall plates

I want to put some kind of stopper on the cables, so that they don't slide down with their own weight.  Initially I thought of making a single loose knot (~2") with the whole bunch, but not sure if this may be detrimental to signal quality.

What do you guys recommend?

(*somewhat old photo*):

[image: 2]

(almost finished):

[image: 3]

Comment: Plug the opening with a firestorm insulation or other firestorm materials, as per code in your region.      You could also use a large zip tie to help prevent the bundle from slipping

Comment: Got an old tennis ball? Cut an "x" at the top and another one at the bottom, shove the cables through it.

Comment: You need a low-voltage mounting ring or low-voltage box (or you can use a regular old-work box, but the LV versions are easier) to properly mount that faceplate.

Comment: Thank you, guys! Yes, an LV-ring is planned, I'll add a picture later.

Comment: You already have a good answer but for the record: **Don't knot cat6 cables**!  There are turn radius restrictions on installing those and if you ignore them, the cables will still work but not as well.  Linked devices may automatically drop down to 1Gb or 100Mb speeds to accommodate, and it'll be difficult for you to figure out why.

Comment: Yep, I've read about min radius. That's what made me ask this Q in the first place :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purchase ring-ended cable ties.

Put a short drywall screw (or other wood screw, assuming wooden studs) through the ring.

Reach in the hole and screw it to the stud that's closest.

Grab the cables and thread the cable tie around them (this can be a high-skill activity one handed in a hole in the wall.)

Pull cables up to have reasonable slack and cinch the cable tie to hold them in place.

Comment: An activity that may have been easier _prior_ to patching up that other little cut in the drywall. :(

Comment: Lucky - closest stud for me was on the left :).  Nevertheless, good tip, @FreeMan!